# Passing a jagged array to a method in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, jagged-arrays, method-call, invalid-argument

I know this is the sort of syntax question that should be easily answered by Google, but it hasn't been.

I have a method that accepts a jagged array, and alters it:

```
public void resetWordList(ref char[][] wordList)
```

It's an array of words, which are each split up into their own separate array of characters--this is for looping reasons later on.

I need to call it from another method:

```
resetWordList(ref wordList[][]);
```

Visual Studio doesn't like the syntax, though. Says that the best overloaded method (i.e., the only method) has "some invalid arguments." I'm either missing something obvious, or there's a syntax detail that needs to be altered.

I've tried messing around with it in several different obvious ways, like putting the length of the outer array in, changing the method call argument to (ref **char** wordList[][]);, other kinds of things. I've also tried RTFM but my textbook and Microsoft's web site haven't covered this rather obscure little tidbit.

Any help/guesses are appreciated.

Comment: You call it with `resetWordList(ref wordList);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `wordList` is a variable in your calling function, just use it without the `[][]`.

Comment: That... should have been obvious. Thanks. This is what happens when I try to program while sick.